# How are min and max of cumulative variables assigned?

Tags: or-tools

I created a routing problem and added some dimension to it. A solution assignment is found and I want to know the cumulative value at each index. I noticed that the `CumulVar` of an assignment does not only have a `Value` method but also `Min` and `Max` methods. Apparently the cumulative variables are implemented in such a way that they can represent intervals. I can see how setting

- `slack_max>0`
- `fix_start_cumul_to_zero=False`

introduces an ambiguity for the cumulative variables as their is a choice in how to start and how much slack to add at each stop. But

**Question**: How are the `Min` and `Max` at each index computed?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Python?

Comment: or-tools is available for C++, Java, C# and Python and there are  differences, but I agree that for this question it is not relevant. Will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Min and Max range of a given node index from `solution.Min(dimension.Cumulvar(index))`

Note you'll get Min and Max exactly the same when `slack_max=0` unless you know something I don't ;)
Assuming you are using an output solution object `solution` and a time dimension `time_dimension`, this will store em as a dict with min-max tuples, you may wish to adapt the output format however you wish:

```
time_dict = {}
for vehicle_id in range(num_vehicles):
  vehicle_time_dict={}
  index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
  start_time = solution.Min(time_dimension.CumulVar(index))
  vehicle_time_dict[index]=(index_min,index_max)
  while not routing.isEnd(index):
    previous_index = index
    index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    index_min = solution.Min(time_dimension.CumulVar(index))
    index_max = solution.Max(time_dimension.CumulVar(index))
    vehicle_time_dict[index]=(index_min,index_max)
  time_dict[vehicle_id]=vehicle_time_dict
```

`routing.IsEnd(index)` returns `True` if it's the last index of that vehicle's route (or anywhere after the last index, so if it's 10 nodes long:

- `routing.IsEnd(8)` will return `False`,
- `routing.IsEnd(9)` will return `True`,
- `routing.IsEnd(10)` will also return `True`, etc)

Comment: by "computed" I meant how does or-tools compute them.